# Regular Expression group division problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

i've got this problem…
i have a string that must be confirmed, the user can insert a concatenation of percent with sign plus or minus as separator (max percent number is 5):

```
+33.22+10.22+11.22+4.43+4.43
```

the first sign is optional, so the previous input should be written also as:

```
33.22+10.22+11.22+4.43+4.43
```

i wrote this regular expression:

```
^(([+-]?\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})|([+-]?\d{1,3}))(([+-]\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})|([+-]\d{1,3})){0,4}$
```

and it works as i receive one match

[image]

the problem (as show in the image) is that i want also the group and the internal part of the input is always seen as one group (+10.22+11.22+4.43)
**i don't want to use a repetition of an atomic expression like this:**

```
^(([+-]?\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})|([+-]?\d{1,3}))(([+-]\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})|([+-]\d{1,3}))(([+-]\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})|([+-]\d{1,3}))(([+-]\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})|([+-]\d{1,3}))(([+-]\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})|([+-]\d{1,3}))$
```

but i want to use the quantifier as i've got some page that use five percent other six percent

**Thank you all!!!!!!!**

Comment: You could do `regex.match(str)` in a loop until you exhaust the input. The regex object is stateful so it would find your pattern, remember the position and the next call will find the next match and so on. I'm not know if that works for you, though.

Comment: You cannot capture all iterations of a repeated capturing group. You may do it in two steps in a JS regex: 1) test for validity, 2) extract all matches if valid. Something like `if (/^(?:[+-]?(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,3})\b)*$/.test(s)) { return s.match(/[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g); }`

Comment: Why did you tag with `asp.net`? What answer do you expect?

Comment: because i'm using asp.net web forms but i'm using the regular expression in javascript,..maybe there is some c# method that is different from javascript method that would work differently and divide group in a different way

Comment: Yes, so you want a C# solution like `Regex.Match(s, @"^([+-]?(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,3})\b)*$")`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot capture all iterations of a [repeated capturing grou](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)p.

You may do it in two steps in a JS regex: 1) test for validity, 2) extract all matches if valid.

```
if (/^(?:[+-]?(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,3})\b){1,5}$/.test(s)) {
    return s.match(/[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g); 
}
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[+-]?(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,3})\b){1,5}` - 1 to 5 repetitions of

  - `[+-]?` - an optional `+`or `-`
  - `(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,3})` - a non-capturing group matching either

    - `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits, `.` and 1 or 2 digits
    - `|` - or
    - `\d{1,3}` - 1, 2 or 3 digits
  - `\b` - a word boundary
- `$` - end of string.

The `.match(/[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g` extracts all substrings following the `-`/`+`  - 1+ digits - optional `.` and 1+ digits pattern from the validated string.

Demo:

```js
var s = "+33.22+10.22+11.22+4.43+4.43";
if (/^(?:[+-]?(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,3})\b){1,5}$/.test(s)) {
    console.log(s.match(/[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g)); 
}
```

In C#, however, you *may* get access to all the captured substrings via `CaptureCollection` of any `Group`:

```
var s = "+33.22+10.22+11.22+4.43+4.43";
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"^([+-]?(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,3})\b){1,5}$");
if (m.Success) 
{
    var captures = m.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
    foreach (var x in captures)
        Console.WriteLine(x);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No match!");
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/qnyrNv). Output:

```
+33.22
+10.22
+11.22
+4.43
+4.43
```

Note the placement of `(...)` in the .NET pattern.

Comment: you miss the part that it must be max 5 items

Comment: @Lorenzo That is the least trouble here. Replace `*` with `{1,5}`.

Comment: i'm testing on edge console, ie console, regex101.com and it doesn't work

Comment: yeah... my fault

Comment: @Lorenzo If you want to speed up your tests you can share them with me using jsfiddle.net or ideone.com services.

Comment: @Lorenzo *What* and *How* does not "work"? Provide the strings you are testing my code snippets against.

Comment: @Lorenzo Please explain what you are trying to achieve.